# Setting onSeekBarChangeListener causes null object exception even when following all the right code

Tags: android

want to create Course Work Data application using fragments and array adapters with list views. 
I'll be able to add to that array list by getting the name (from an EditText) and the grade from a textiew/seekbar combination with the onSeekBarChangeListener. 
 Previously, I had a problem where the textview would not update when I adjusted the seekbar.  I realized that was because I was doing everything in the button handler (duh). 
 But now after I took the code out of the button and only left what should be there and added it to the top of the oncreate method (below setcontentview), it crashes.  The code is attached. what is the solution?

```
 public class AddCourseWorkItem extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_course_work_item);
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();


        ft.add(R.id.course_work_item_container, new CourseWorkItemFragment());
        ft.commit();

       final CourseWorkItem cwi = new CourseWorkItem();
       final ArrayList<CourseWorkItem> itemlist;
        CourseWorkApplication app = (CourseWorkApplication) getApplication();
        itemlist = app.getArrayList();
      final   EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.homework_edit_text);
        SeekBar gradeSeekBar;
        gradeSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.grade_seekbar);
        final TextView gradeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.grade_textview);

        gradeSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                gradeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        cwi.setName(name.getText().toString());
        cwi.setGrade(gradeTextView.getText().toString());
        cwi.setCategory("Homework");

        Button addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_item_button);


        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                itemlist.add(cwi);
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = name.getText() + " added";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;


                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();


                finish();


            }
        });

    }
    }
```

Also, the last curly brace that is above this line of text, belongs in the code.

Here is my **LogCat:**

> 04-06 22:31:52.923 1562-1562/bcs421.michaelziminski.hwk.courseworkdata
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                            Process: bcs421.michaelziminski.hwk.courseworkdata, PID: 1562
>                                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{bcs421.michaelziminski.hwk.courseworkdata/bcs421.michaelziminski.hwk.courseworkdata.AddCourseWorkItem}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.SeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(android.widget.SeekBar$OnSeekBarChangeListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.SeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(android.widget.SeekBar$OnSeekBarChangeListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                                at
>   bcs421.michaelziminski.hwk.courseworkdata.AddCourseWorkItem.onCreate(AddCourseWorkItem.java:47)
>                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

**Activity layout xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="bcs421.michaelziminski.hwk.courseworkdata.AddCourseWorkItem">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/course_work_item_container">

</FrameLayout>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/add_item_button"
    android:text="@string/add_coursework_item_label"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment Layout xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".CourseWorkItemFragment">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/coursework_item_label"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/category_label"/>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/category_spinner">
    </Spinner>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name_label"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/homework_edit_text"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/grade_label"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="186dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/grade_seekbar"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/grade_label_placeholder"
        android:id="@+id/grade_textview"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post error logcat here

Comment: please post the logcat and xml layout